# How to turn off a Group header in SfListView?

Tags: c#, xamarin, grouping, syncfusion

I have a problem.I want to turn off a Group header in SfListView.I read on the forums to turn off IsStickyGroupHeader,I did it but  IsStickyGroupHeader="False" does not work.Maybe I understand something wrong.Please help me.Thank you

```
 <syncfusion:SfListView
                x:Name="listView"
                Grid.Row="0"
                ItemSize="40"
                IsStickyGroupHeader="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding contactsinfo}"
                SelectionMode="None">

                <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <StackLayout
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                            Orientation="Vertical"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center">
                                            <Label
                                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                                Text="{Binding ContactName}"
                                                TextColor="#474747"
                                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />

                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Grid>

                                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray" HeightRequest="1" />

                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
            </syncfusion:SfListView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the GroupHeader by using the [GroupHeaderSize](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/xamarin/Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.SfListView.html#Syncfusion_ListView_XForms_SfListView_GroupHeaderSize) as **0**. Please refer to the following code snippets,

```
<ListView:SfListView 
                x:Name="listView"
                Grid.Row="0"
                ItemSize="40"
                GroupHeaderSize="0"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ContactsInfo}"
                SelectionMode="None">
```

You can also refer to our user guidance document regarding the same,
UG link: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/listview/grouping#height-customization

Also, if you are using [SfListView.AutoFitMode](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/xamarin/Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.SfListView.html#Syncfusion_ListView_XForms_SfListView_AutoFitMode) as **Height** or **DynamicHeight**, then the items size will be calculated based on the template elements. Hence, you can customize the [GroupHeaderTemplate](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/xamarin/Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.SfListView.html#Syncfusion_ListView_XForms_SfListView_GroupHeaderTemplate) with Height **0**.

```
<ListView:SfListView 
        x:Name="listView"
        Grid.Row="0"
        AutoFitMode="DynamicHeight"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ContactsInfo}"
        SelectionMode="None">
    <ListView:SfListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell Height="0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView:SfListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

Refer the following documentation regarding the same,
UG link: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/listview/grouping#group-header-customization